# How to do fast update queries in an Excel file with vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm trying to make an update clause with an Excel sheet that contains about 2958 rows (32538 cells in total). First I'm identifying which cells contain incorrect data (for example, a cell with characters in a numeric column) and then replace these incorrect data with value that I want.

With small Excel sheets it works fine, but when viewing a larger sheet, the program freezes after some time.

How can I make fast update queries and handle a lot of data?

PD: Sorry for not leaving the code of the update . Here is how I am doing .

```
Protected Friend Sub reemplazarDato(ByVal columna As String, ByVal data As String, ByVal con As String)
    Dim cmd As String = ""
    For Each itm In arrayErrores
        cmd = "UPDATE [" & obtenerHojaActual(columna, con) & "$] SET [" & columna & "]='" & dato & "' WHERE [" & columna & "]='" & itm & "'"
        Try
            conexion.Open()
            Dim comando As New OleDbCommand(cmd, conexion)
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
            comando.Dispose()
            conexion.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            repairmanMessage("Error inesperado", ex.Message, My.Resources._error).ShowDialog()
            conexion.Close()
        End Try
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to show how you are currently performing the update ...

Comment: Ok, I paste the code now. Sorry.

Comment: Open and close the connection *outside* the loop - you only need to do it once.

Comment: I wouldn't update one field at a time if that's what you are doing.. I would use parameters! Make sure you have index/primary keys and use them. You're not using the data variable parameter, you use dato.

Comment: Using parameters, you could also avoid creating a new DbCommand object in a loop -just set the new `.Value`.  Transactions *generally* speed up multiple updates, but I am not sure if they would work with Excel

Comment: You right Plutonix... I've tried using parameters with Excel, but for some reason did not work me . I will try again to see ...!

Comment: Wow, when i try to use parameters, the program says "Operation  must use an updateable query"... Excel cannot support parameters? @Plutonix